# Office 365 API for Word

Tags: office365, office365-apps

We are exploring Office 365 API & are in initial stage. We are figuring out if we can move our Word Docs in Office 365.

Does Office 365 provide an API for Word Processing like writing Macros.

Comment: I am unsure exactly what you are asking, however our company has made a huge leap into azure and I have found myself looking at Office Graph quite a bit. I would suggest you look into that api.

Answer (score 4):

No, Office 365 APIs do not cover word processing. What exactly are you trying to do? If you're trying to leverage or extend the power of Word, you should check out [apps for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220060(v=office.15).aspx). If you want to use data that an organization stores with Office 365, e.g. if you want to get all the documents belonging to a user X for example, then you should use [Office 365 APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/dn605892(v=office.15)).

Comment: Hi, @thecanteen, how about get one of the excel data in office 365 ? Read and write into the excel file in office 365. Can office 365 APIs can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, I don't believe Microsoft offers such an API for Word processing (and pretty much every other format processing). So you will need to use third-party API or third-party components in your API. As example, Aspose offers both and has free plan (Dislaimer: I am affiliated with the company). Check out [Aspose Words Cloud](https://products.aspose.cloud/words/cloud)