# Is there a Microsoft Graph MS Word API?

Tags: ms-word, office365, microsoft-graph-api

### Question

Are there actually any Graph API endpoints for the Office 365 version of Word at the moment?

(And, if not, are they planned?)

### Where I've looked

I've found the documentation for [Excel API in Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/excel-concept-overview), [Outlook API in Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onenote-api-overview), [OneNote API in Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onenote-api-overview), but I cannot find any mention of a Word API.

There's no mention of Word in the [Productivity section of Graph Overview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview-major-services#productivity) Official docs.

And there's no sign of it in the [Graph Explorer Samples](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#):

[image: Graph Explorer Samples list]

And there don't seem to be any sub-projects related to Word in the [Microsoft Graph GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoftgraph?page=1).

### Side notes

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201971/office-365-api-for-word) asks a similar thing about the Office 365 API.  I'm not sure if the Graph API is a rebranding of the Office 365 API, which now seems to be end of life [according to the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/api-catalog)?

Ultimately what we're looking for is a replacement for the [Office PIAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2017) that we can use from an Azure hosted web app to build Word documents.  We've been using Open XML, but we need dynamic page numbering which OpenXML doesn't support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today there is no Word API available under the Microsoft Graph other than managing the file and it's permissions when it's seating in SharePoint/OneDrive for Business.
There is a [UserVoice entry](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/32201329-add-microsoft-word-endpoints-to-the-microsoft-grap) supporting the idea.
There used to be [APIs provided by Office Online Server/Office Web Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838422/is-there-any-office-web-apps-server-api-available) but I don't think it fits your scenario.
So as you're pointing today the only ways to modify a word document via an API that are available seem to be the interop assemblies, the [Office Add-Ins SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=visual-studio) or third party APIs.

Comment: is this still the case today?

Comment: Yes, no word API has been added to date